# How to build config-drive enabled image in openstack?

Tags: image, openstack

Vendors build images with metadata stored in them. How can I build such images in openstack? Definitely, not by using snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Disk-image-builder https://docs.openstack.org/developer/diskimage-builder:

```
export IMAGE_NAME=ubuntu-cloud-image
export DIB_DEV_USER_USERNAME=devuser
export DIB_DEV_USER_PASSWORD=abc123
export DIB_DEV_USER_PWDLESS_SUDO=Yes
export DIB_CLOUD_INIT_DATASOURCES="ConfigDrive, Openstack"
disk-image-create ubuntu vm devuser cloud-init-datasources -o $IMAGE_NAME
```